# SpriteKit adding UIView on top of scene touches not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I haven't been able to figure out why my buttons or any touchable elements don't work when i add custom UIView on top of my SpriteKit scene (is shows as expected just the touches don't work). I've also tried setting userInteractionEnabled on scene's view and scene itself and it didn't work. This is excerpt from my code:

```
 ShopView *shopView = [[ShopView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.02, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.2, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.96, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.6)];

        shopView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.gameScene.view addSubview:shopView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution that fits me better than just a view. I can use storyboards with it and it keeps my code cleaner. I just created modal view controller with transparent background. I'm working for IOS8 so the code is as follows (in case someone has the same problems):

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];

        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

        [self vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've provided, I can only assume that the view you are placing on top is capturing all the touches (like placing your hands under a running faucet - the water doesn't reach the sink underneath), and nothing is actually reaching the scene underneath. Consider a different approach. I don't think you are fully understanding how to use views and scenes together.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info in my post. Basically all the touches go through my View and hit the scene underneath. What i would like is to capture the touches on the View and not let them pass through to the scene bellow.

Comment: Have you implemented touch event handlers for the overlay UIView (`touchesBegan` etc.)?

Comment: jonogilmur: yes. I've also tried UIGestureRecognizers. Doesn't detect my touches.

Comment: @y0gie007 I can only think that perhaps your subview is being placed behind the scene. Can you confirm that it is definitely sitting on top?